# How to show custom notifications in Android like Large image or with Multiple buttons

Tags: android

I am developing an android app, i need to show different type of Notifications. I have already created Notification Channel, Notification Builder and Notification Manager but still when i am firing a push notification from Firebase, and if the app is killed from the back ground I am getting a normal notification(Default Style). If I am pushing a notification while the app is running, I am getting the correct style(Big Picture and extra buttons) of notification.

How to solve this issue? I need the styles always(24 X 7), whether the app is live or killed, just like all other apps in market.

```
public class NotificationHelper {

    public static void displayNotification(Context context, String title, String body) {

        Intent  intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        PendingIntent acceptPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 101, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        PendingIntent declinePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 102, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources.getSystem(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        @SuppressLint({"WrongConstant", "NewApi", "LocalSuppress"}) Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setLargeIcon(picture)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(picture)
                        .bigLargeIcon((Bitmap) null))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationMgr = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        mNotificationMgr.notify(1, notification);
    }
}

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        //if the message contains data payload
        //It is a map of custom keyvalues
        //we can read it easily
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
            //handle the data message here
        }

        //getting the title and the body
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

            NotificationHelper.displayNotification(getApplicationContext(), title, body);
        }

        //then here we can use the title and body to build a notification
    }
}

//inside main activity

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                            Log.d("token", "Generated Token: " + token);
                        }else {
                            Log.d("token", "Token not generated: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: i think you have to read this which is clearly told you about your answer https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification Good day!

Comment: Hey @VipulChauhan i think u didn't get my question. I am able to get the style BUT when the app is Killed or not in foreground, it is showing the default style of the notification with no extra buttons or Big Image.

Comment: ohh sorry buddy so for this you have to start foreground service this will help you to keep your application live when user clear it from the recent apps

Comment: @VipulChauhan thanks for the help, i do appreciate it. Can u please write a set of code so that i'll have a better idea about the service that work exactly for notifications.